# Bash average with scale=2

Tags: bash

Trying to create a simple calculating the average from say quiz numbers. I do something like this but am getting errors.

```
echo "Enter your name and 3 quiz scores: "
read name q1 q2 q3

let avg=`echo "scale=2; (q1+q2+q3)/3" | bc`
```

Lets say the user enters mike 12 14 15. The average return value should be 13.66

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try

```
avg=`echo "scale=2; ($q1+$q2+$q3)/3" | bc`
```

Or, more succinctly (and more efficiently):

```
avg=`bc <<<"scale=2; ($q1+$q2+$q3)/3"`
```

- You were missing `$` prefixes for the variable references.
- `let` is used for *Bash*'s *integer-only* arithmetic, so you can't use it assign the output of your `bc` command - a decimal fraction - to a variable (a decimal fraction such as `13.66` is not a valid arithmetic expression in Bash).
  A normal variable assignment will do.

Comment: yeah this works. I used the let command in an earlier problem and I thought the logic would be the same. thanks